# How to Edit Excel with EPPLUS and send it as attachment

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, epplus

i have the following code, which it is working, it opens a file stream from an embedded Xlsx saves it on a memorystream then pass the value to the attachment and send it with no problem.

```
Private Sub SendFile2()
    Dim path As String = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/RQM.xlsx")
    Using fileST As FileStream = IO.File.OpenRead(path)
        Dim memStream As New MemoryStream()
        memStream.SetLength(fileST.Length)
        fileST.Read(memStream.GetBuffer(), 0, CInt(fileST.Length))


          '' Code for MailMessage and SMTP goes here

           MailMsg.Attachments.Add(New Attachment(memStream, "myFile.xlsx", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"))

        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Now im trying to do some edition (adding some values to that file, but still working in a memorystream) but i am having some problems
i've added

```
       Using pck As ExcelPackage = New ExcelPackage(memStream)
            Dim xlswb As ExcelWorkbook = pck.Workbook
            Dim xlsws As ExcelWorksheet = xlswb.Worksheets.First
            xlsws.Cells(20, 4).Value = "HELLO WORLD"
            pck.SaveAs(memStream)
       End Using
```

Which when i put breakpoints i see pck getting the value of MemStream with a lenght of 83084 (the value of the original file) 81kb xlsx, when i add the value to the cell the lenght of memStream is 162143 so it seems it does some modifications, however when i send again the memstream trough

```
MailMsg.Attachments.Add(New Attachment(memStream, "myFile.xlsx", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"))
```

i receive a file of 165b, and i'm not sure what i am doing wrong.
Any help would be apreciated

Edit: 
Well i wasn't able to save it with the same memStream so instead i did this.

```
memStream2 = New MemoryStream(pck.GetAsByteArray())
MailMsg.Attachments.Add(New Attachment(memStream2, "myFile2.xlsx", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"))
```

And that worked as a charm. Hope is useful to anyone.